# How to create custom function for Vue JS like created() hook?

Tags: vue.js

How should i create a plugin that adds a function named`structure` like `created()` hook to all components ?

Also i want my plugin have access to `structure` return value.

```js
export default {
   structure() {
       // Access to context
   }
}
```

I have to mention i use Inertia JS.

Comment: What would be the purpose of this `structure()` hook?

Comment: You can add a mixin that calls this.structure in this.created, or else. Consider explaining your case

Answer (score 0):

You could use Vue [Mixins](https://vuejs.org/api/options-composition.html#mixins) or [Composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#composables).

Both will can provide you with some shared functions and variables. But I don't know a way to define new hooks in Vue like created(). I will have to start your functions in created() yourself. Of course, you can override the existing Vue hooks with Mixins.

Mixins are very handy but **No Longer Recommended**

There is no `created()` in the [Composition API](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html), so you have to use `onBeforeMount()` or `onMounted()`

Here is a very basic example using both techniques

```js
const { createApp, ref, onBeforeMount } = Vue;

const myMixin = {
  created() {
    console.log('myMixin: created()')
  }
}

const myComposable = () => {
    onBeforeMount(() => {
       console.log('myComposable: onBeforeMount()')    
    })
    const myFunction = () => console.log('myFunction()')    
    return { myFunction }
}

const App = {
  setup() {
    const { myFunction } = myComposable()
    return  { myFunction }
  },
  mixins: [myMixin]
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <button @click="myFunction()">myFunction()</button>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```